# In R, what is the best way to add the p-values from comparisons between groups to a grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, ggpubr, grouped-bar-chart

Please, consider the following MWE.

EDIT: Thanks to the very good comments, it became clear that there were not enough data in my very simplified MWE to do the statistical comparisons between the groups. Due to this shortcoming, I've rewritten the MWE:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# Create random data
set.seed(123456789)
n_participants <- 100
participant_id <- 1:n_participants
group <- sample(c("A", "B"), size = n_participants, replace = TRUE)
gene1 <- sample(0:1, size = n_participants, replace = TRUE)
gene2 <- sample(0:1, size = n_participants, replace = TRUE)
gene3 <- sample(0:1, size = n_participants, replace = TRUE)
gene4 <- sample(0:1, size = n_participants, replace = TRUE)
gene5 <- sample(0:1, size = n_participants, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(participant_id, group, gene1, gene2, gene3, gene4, gene5)

head(data)
#>   participant_id group gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4 gene5
#> 1              1     B     1     0     1     0     1
#> 2              2     B     0     0     1     1     0
#> 3              3     A     1     1     0     1     0
#> 4              4     B     0     0     1     1     0
#> 5              5     A     0     1     1     1     0
#> 6              6     B     0     0     1     1     0

# Run chisq.tests to compare the categorical variables gene1:gene5 between groups "A" and "B"
data_long <- data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = gene1:gene5, names_to = "gene", values_to = "value")

test_results <- data_long %>% 
  group_by(gene) %>% 
  summarize(p_value = chisq.test(table(group, value))$p.value)

test_results
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   gene  p_value
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 gene1   0.394
#> 2 gene2   0.103
#> 3 gene3   0.463
#> 4 gene4   0.437
#> 5 gene5   0.423

# For plotting, create probability table
prob_table <- data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(gene1 = mean(gene1, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
            gene2 = mean(gene2, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
            gene3 = mean(gene3, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
            gene4 = mean(gene4, na.rm = TRUE) * 100,
            gene5 = mean(gene5, na.rm = TRUE) * 100)

# Thereafter convert to long form data for ggplot
data_to_ggplot <- pivot_longer(prob_table, gene1:gene5,
                               names_to = "gene", values_to = "Percentage")

# Plot data
ggplot(data_to_ggplot, aes(fill = group, x = gene, y = Percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.6) +
  ylim(0, 100) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Percentage") +
  ggtitle("Prevalence of certain genes in groups A and B") +
  theme_classic() +   
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In order to get the image below, what method do you suggest to add the p-values from the object `test_results`? Can `geom_signif` be used in this type of a situation?

[image]

Comment: to compare 2 means you need at least mean1, mean2, i think it is 41 and 56 for gene1 but you need also the variance of the mean and the sample size (if a t test is suitable).

Comment: Why not just run your hypothesis tests first, collect the data in a dataframe, and add it to the plot with `geom_text()`?

Comment: @Wael, I cannot believe I missed that... the original data was longer, but I thought that I could make this example with a simple data table. Of course there is no chance for a comparison with only these data.

Comment: Could you, try to change your data with some sample values ?

Comment: @Wael, certainly, I apologize for being crazy enough not to give the full data. I've edited the whole question anew now. I thought about stat_compare_means originally, but I guess that is not feasible here/not even necessary. Can `geom_signif` be used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes definitely you can do it with `ggsignif` package

you find below how to add `geom_signif` arguments to your plot

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(ggsignif)
# Plot data
ggplot(data_to_ggplot, aes(fill = group, x = gene, y = Percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.6) +
  ylim(0, 100) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Percentage") +
  ggtitle("Prevalence of certain genes in groups A and B") +
  theme_classic() +   
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 14))+
  geom_signif(
    y_position = rep(65,5), xmin = 1:5-0.2, xmax = 1:5+0.2,
    annotation = round(test_results$p_value,3),tip_length = 0.4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you so much.

My impression is that in (grouped) bar charts the workflow depicted here, by your help, might be a winner:
1) separate data frame (and process) for doing the chisq.tests;
2) separate data frame for a probability table, enabling the plotting of a percentage type of bar chart for the categorical variable(s);
3) combining of the chisq.test results and the (grouped) bar chart with `ggsignif::geom_signif()`.

In contrast, for continuous variables, everything is more straightforward, as `stat_compare_means` can be used straight with `ggplot`.

Comment: (I must add here that of course the statistical comparison (model) in question has to be clarified in the footnote of the graph.)